# Proof of Continuity Validity: $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

I want to show that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0, \infty)$.

Is it valid to argue that $\forall x_0, x_0 \neq 0, \lim_{x \rightarrow x_0} \frac{1}{x} = \frac{1}{x_0}$, so for all $x$ in the interval $f(x)$ is continuous, so $f$ is continuous? I was wondering, as all of the arguments I have seen use $\epsilon-\delta$ style arguments.

Comment: No, I just wanted to make sure that I was thinking about this correctly, as this seems much simpler than using $\epsilon-\delta.$ For some reason, all of the books I've seen only use  $\epsilon-\delta.$ Is there any reason why this is done?

Comment: As I said stating that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ by stating $f(x) \to f(x_0)$ is shuffling definitions -- not really a proof.

Comment: But aren't you relying on the definition of a limit, instead of relying on the definition of continuity?

Answer (score 0):

If you *assume* that the following is true

> (1) for all $x_0\neq 0$, $\lim_{x\to x_0}=\frac{1}{x_0}$

then it is logically correct to say that *since* (1) is true, $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ by *definition*. But you are not proving anything but rewriting the problem by definition of continuity.

What you are supposed to do is reproducing the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof for (1), which is the whole point of the exercise.

Comment: Assuming that I know that the limit is true. I was just trying reducing the problem to one that I already know how to solve.

Comment: It is logically correct though, you are losing the whole point of that problem. You are not reducing anything but *rewriting* the problem by definition. What you need to show is exactly that "the limit is true".